# Tag synonyms ([interval], [range])

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Three days ago (2014-04-06), I created the [interval](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interval), unaware that [range](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range) had been created on 2014-03-27.  What to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose synonymizing master [interval](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interval) ← synonym [range](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range).

"Interval" is a less ambiguous term than "range", since it invokes the idea of [interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic).  "Range", on the other hand, has [multiple meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range):

- an interval
- the set of allowable values for a variable
- the set of possible output values of a function
- the difference between the lowest and highest values of a set

I've [proposed the synonym](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/interval/synonyms), but since there are only two users who are eligible to vote for it, I'd like to see some consensus here.